# Вызвать метод из экземпляра класса-родителя

Tags: java

У меня есть экземпляр класса, который унаследует Class1 который в свою очередь унаследует Class2 который унаследует Class3. У всех этих классов есть метод test(), но мне надо вызвать только тот, который в Class3, без помощи, или с помощью reflection.

Проще говоря мне надо сделать что-то такое:

`super.super.super.test();`

Изменять Class1, Class2, Class3 я не могу.

Comment: Не получится.
Java точно знает, к какому типу относится Ваш экземпляр класса, даже если привести тип к объекту супер-класса, то при вызове выполнится именно переопределенный метод в наследнике.

Comment: Из вопроса не ясно в итоге кто от кого наследуется.... казалось, что Class3 - это самый нижний потомок, но по коду `super.super.super.test();` всё в точности наоборот

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Так и есть, Class3 самый нижний. Я этим хотел сказать что допустим у нас есть Class0 который унаследует Class1, и далее мы обращаемся к родителю Class0 выражением super затем еще раз к родителю Class1 и еще раз к родителю Class2 тем самым попадая в Class3 и вызывая метод test в нём.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы не переопределили метод `test` в классах наследниках тогда код:

```
public static void main(String[] array){ 
     Class0 class0=new Class0(); 
     class0.test();
}
```

Если Вы переопределили метод `test` в классах наследниках  тогда код:
Способ 1) с перегрузкой метода `test`

```
public class Class0 extends Class1(){  

     @Override
     public void test(){ 
        //код
    } 

     public void test(int i){  
         Class3 class3=new Class3(); 
          class3.test();
    } 

}  

public class Main{ 
     public static void main(String[] array){ 
          Class0 class0=new Class0(); 
          class0.test(0);
     } 
}
```

переменая `i` служит костылём чтоб java поняла к чему мы обращаемся.
Способ 2) без перегрузки метода `test`

```
public class Class0 extends Class1(){  

     @Override
     public void test(){ 
        //код
    } 

     public void testClass3(){  
         Class3 class3=new Class3(); 
          class3.test();
    } 

}  

public class Main{ 
     public static void main(String[] array){ 
          Class0 class0=new Class0(); 
          class0.testClass3();
     } 
}
```